# Why am I getting this error message for unused argument?

Tags: r

I've been writing this section of code to create error bars for a graph that I've created but in the final section where I define df2 I am getting the error message saying:

> Error in data_summary(antioxidants, varname = "expression", groupnames = c("sex",  :
> unused arguments (varname = "expression", groupnames = c("sex", "gene"))

Would anyone be able to explain why I am receiving this message and what I can do to fix it?
Thanks in advance.

```
df <- antioxidants
df$gene <- as.factor(df$gene)
head(df)

data_summary <- function(antioxidants, expression, genes){
  require(plyr)
  summary_func <- function(x, col){
    c(mean = mean(x[[col]], na.rm=TRUE),
      sd = sd(x[[col]], na.rm=TRUE))
  }
  data_sum <- ddply(antioxidants, genes, .fun=summary_func,
                  expression)
  data_sum <- rename(data_sum, c("mean" = varname))
  return(data_sum)
}

df2 <- data_summary(antioxidants, varname = "expression", 
                    groupnames = c("sex", "gene"))
df2$gene=as.factor(df2$gene)
head(df2)
```

Comment: When you are calling your function `data_summary`, you supply 2 arguments `varname` and `groupnames` that don't exist in the function, which has 3 arguments `antioxidants`, `expression` and `genes`

Comment: Your use of `require` is incorrect and prone to perhaps-difficult errors (unrelated to *this* error). If you're going to use `require`, then get its return value and do something with it. If you don't want its return value, then use `library`. Using `require` by itself is setting yourself up for unnecessary trouble.

Comment: BTW `plyr` has been retired long back and now almost everything can be done with `dplyr`. Can you share your data with `dput(antioxidants)` and show the output that you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you for everyone's advice, I have managed to amend the code now and I've got the error bars for my graph :)